# Генераторы списков

Tags: python

Есть простой цикл:

```
 for i in res:
    g = nets(i[1])
      if g is not None:
          ......
```

Как заменить на генераторы списков?

```
 [nets(i[1]) for i in res]
```

Answer (score 1):

Простейший вариант:

```
[nets(i[1]) for i in res if nets(i[1])]
```

Но, во-первых, тут двойной вызов функции nets, а во-вторых, нам некуда пристроить код, который у тебя обозначен многоточием.

Есть другое решение:

```
def do_something(g):
    .......

map(do_something, filter([nets(i[1]) for i in res]))
```

Если очень хочется сделать всё это ленивым, можно просто использовать ленивые filter и map.

Comment: Я варианты смотрю, как будет быстрее работать.

Comment: Тогда советую использовать imap и ifilter из itertools